# How to completely hide AdView if the request failed (maybe offline)?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I want the AdView to be set to GONE (so that user don't see large empty space) if after the 60 sec. refresh, it failed to load an ad (maybe offline?). But I still want it to keep on refreshing until it succeeds then make it visible again.

I'm being straight to the point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AdListener

```
public abstract class AdListener {
public void onAdLoaded();
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode); //hide adview here
public void onAdOpened();
public void onAdClosed();
 public void onAdLeftApplication();
  }
```

A separate class extending AdListener may be defined, or you can choose to inline an AdListener object:

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
@Override
public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
 // hide or refresh adview 
}
});
```

read more [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner?hl=en#ad_lifecycle_event_callbacks)

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame that I was not able to find this even when I searched for the exact wordings.

Comment: Beware if you do set the visibility of the AdView to GONE. You will no longer be able to successfully load it: "Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad." Unfortunately you cannot just set the visibility back to VISIBLE in onAdLoaded() because it won't even be called if your AdView is not showing in the first place.

Comment: As above, this won't really help you. If the adview is set to INVISIBLE or GONE, it won't refresh, ever